# Term for resonance between Author and Title

Tags: terminology, puns, book-title

Often books will have title that is a pun on the [author's name](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18240402-faster-than-lightning) or in anonymous works a euonymous nom-de-plume. Sometimes in scholarly works the title unironically reflects an [author's aptronymic occupation](https://www.askprofessorbird.com/purchase-books).
Is there an over-arching term for this particular correspondence between a book's title and author?

Comment: What is [euonymous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euonymus) supposed to mean?

Comment: Pretty sounding, *euphonious*?

Comment: A "euonym" is a moniker well suited to the person, place, or thing named.

Comment: I would call the first example a _punning title_ and say that the author in the second has an appropriate name. I don't know of any term that covers both cases.

Comment: _Euonymous_ is a wonderful word from Greek _εὐώνυμος_ 'euonym' + _-ous_ suffix, but it is rare. _OED_ defines it as "Well or felicitously named." and provides the only citation "The Peace Society and its euonymous president, Mr. Pease." from 1864.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of no term that applies to the case of books in particular, but there is one that applies generally. The person whose name answers to these characteristics is said to be *aptly named*.

([ref.](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/au+nom+pr%C3%A9destin%C3%A9))  The aptly-named Pieter Klock was one of the foremost watchmakers of Amsterdam.

There is another term that is also applicable generally: the name is said to be a *predestined name*.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Vietnam_Magazine/gDYWAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22predestined+name%22&pg=RA5-PA24&printsec=frontcover))  When peace was signed at Aachen ( Aix - la - Chapelle ) in 1748 , the French Company sent to Cochinchina Pierre Poivre ( a predestined name for the job he was given ) with mission of establishing there a commercial center , and of ...

(*"Poivre" is the word for "pepper" in French.*)

Comment: [Nominative determinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism) is another name for this.

Comment: Aptronym is another term for the above mentioned "Aptly Named"

Comment: @Palantir For your information: you can answer your own question, ie, write an answer yourself.

Comment: @StuartF Rather than another name, it is a theory attempting to explain why people are sometimes aptly named.

Comment: @Palantir From what I can read in the Wikipedia, "[aptronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptronym)"  is better suited as it is used specifically for person's names that "coincide" out of sheer luck. "Aptly" applies to all sorts of namings, and those are often the result of an _intended_ association of a place or thing with a given particularity ("At the junction of the two main roads intersecting the town stood the aptly named Corner Cafe…).

Comment: I included the terms euonym and aptronym in my original question to signal that neither was inclusive enough in this case.